# Position of median within a list

Tags: c++, arrays, position, median

I have an unsorted array and I need the position of the median. I know there are several algorithms to calculate the median of a given array in O(n), but all of them include some kind of reordering of the array, like in median of medians and random selection.

I'm not interested int he median itself, only its position within the array interests me.

Is there any way I can do this in O(n)? Keeping track of all the swaps will create a massive overhead, so I'm looking for another solution.

Comment: The median doesn't have to be in the input. Example: The median of [1, 1, 2, 10] is 1.5

Comment: To be clear: you want to find the median in O(n) without modifying the list? You cannot make a copy?

Comment: @leonbloy (right, disregard...)

Comment: The 1.5 value is only the median by convention. The values 1 and 2 would also be reasonable interpretations of the median. [link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Median)

Comment: "I'm not interested int he median itself, only its position within the array" ... we'll, given the position you have the value inmmediately, so I don't get this caveat

Comment: 1.5 would be the Mean Average. Median and Mode are two other kinds of averages. To be clear is the Array unsorted when you get?

Comment: @Sqeaky "I have an unsorted array ..."

Comment: @leemes I think there won't be much difference whether I select 1 or 2 in this case as the median, but I'd like to choose always the lower/higher value.

Answer (score 5):

Let's say you have an array of data, and you would like to find its median:

```
double data[MAX_DATA] = ...
```

Create an array of indexes, and initialize each index to its own position, like this:

```
int index[MAX_DATA];
for (int i = 0 ; i != MAX_DATA ; i++) {
    index[i] = i;
}
```

Now implement the linear median algorithm with the following changes:

- When the original algorithm compares `data[i]` to `data[j]`, replace with a comparison of `data[index[i]]` to `data[index[j]]`
- When the original algorithm swaps `data[i]` and `data[j]`, swap `index[i]` and `index[j]` instead.

Since the elements of `data` remain in their place all the time, the modified algorithm will produce the position of the median in the unmodified array, rather than its position in the array with some elements moved to different spots.

In C++ you can implement this with pointers instead of indexes, and use [`std::nth_element`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/nth_element/) on the container of pointers, like this:

```
vector<int> data = {1, 5, 2, 20, 10, 7, 9, 1000};
vector<const int*> ptr(data.size());
transform(data.begin(), data.end(), ptr.begin(), [](const int& d) {return &d;});
auto mid = next(ptr.begin(), data.size() / 2);
nth_element(ptr.begin(), mid, ptr.end(), [](const int* lhs, const int* rhs) {return *lhs < *rhs;});
ptrdiff_t pos = *mid - &data[0];
cout << pos << endl << data[pos] << endl;
```

Here is a [link to a demo on ideone](http://ideone.com/0WM07M).

Comment: why not use `std::nth_element` with a lambda to compare the original data on this array of indices?

Comment: @rhalbersma You are right, I forgot about the override that supplies a comparator! I edited the answer to reflect your comment. Thanks!

Comment: Is this method really linear? It doesn't seem like it since it uses two indicies.

Comment: I thought about this idea, but I have many medians to find, so I'm looking for a faster solution, this will almost double the time needed. 

I just tested it and it increases the time needed by almost 60%.

--This relates to the keep track method

Comment: made my comment into a proper answer.

Comment: @Max It is very strange that the amount of time increased so much. Did you try using a pointer-based approach (see the edit and a demo)?

Comment: BTW, you need to use `(size() - 1)/2` as offset to correctly get the median for an odd number of elements and 0-based arary indexing.

Comment: @rhalbersma Why? Integer division would truncate the result of the division for odd numbers anyway. For even numbers, `(size()-1)/2` would be picking the smaller of the two elements for the median, while `size()/2` would be picking the larger one. Technically, neither one is the median, so I think it's OK to pick one or the other.

Comment: OK, you are right. For non-arithmetic types there is a choice of medians.

Comment: Just implemented the method suggested by rhalbersma and it needs 4 times more time than Hoare's selection algorithm. I moved the construction of any variables outside of the loop and passed only references to them in order to increase speed further.

So simply keeping track of everything is two times faster.

I ran the algorithms 400k times and used unsorted vectors of size 9.

Answer (score 1):

Here's working example that generates a secondary array of indices, and finds the median of the input array through `std::nth_element` and an indirect comparison

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>

int main()
{
   // input data, big and expensive to sort or copy
   std::string big_data[] = { "hello", "world", "I", "need", "to", "get", "the", "median", "index" };    

   auto const N = std::distance(std::begin(big_data), std::end(big_data));
   auto const M = (N - 1) / 2; // 9 elements, median is 4th element in sorted array

   // generate indices
   std::vector<int> indices;
   auto value = 0;
   std::generate_n(std::back_inserter(indices), N, [&](){ return value++; });

   // find median of input array through indirect comparison and sorting
   std::nth_element(indices.begin(), indices.begin() + M, indices.end(), [&](int lhs, int rhs){ 
       return big_data[lhs] < big_data[rhs]; 
   });
   std::cout << indices[M] << ":" << big_data[indices[M]] << "\n";

   // check, sort input array and confirm it has the same median
   std::sort(std::begin(big_data), std::end(big_data));
   std::cout << M << ":" << big_data[M] << "\n";
}
```

Online [output](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=cfe39460232d8b6d145e7a7f67004296-964d511b763697b11567dd233d45657b).

This algorithm is guaranteed of `O(N)` complexity, since it is the sum of `std::generate_n` and `std::nth_element`, both of which are `O(N)` in their input data.

Answer (score 0):

There is an O(n log n) algorithm for keeping track of median on an infinite stream of numbers. (As you don't want to alter the list, you can as well treat it as a stream.) The algorithm involves two heaps; one always points to the maximum number in the lower half and the other points to the minimum number in the higher half. The algorithm is explained here: http://www.ardendertat.com/2011/11/03/programming-interview-questions-13-median-of-integer-stream/. You can use the same code with minimum customization.